# Django / Mypy: Incompatible type on for models

Tags: python, django, mypy

I'm working on a Django project and I'm using mypy for type checking.
To enable type checking for django I'm using the [django-stubs](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs) package.

This works great, but I've now run into a situation where mypy is throwing two errors that I seem unable to solve:

```
Item "None" of "Optional[Season]" has no attribute "league"

Incompatible type for "league" of "Match" (got "Union[ForeignKey[Union[League, Combinable], League], Any]", expected "Union[League, Combinable, None]")
```

These errors are raised for the code below. I'm initiating (but not creating / saving to the database) an instance of the `Match` model.

```
match = Match(
            home_team=home_team,
            away_team=away_team,
            league=home_team.seasons.last().league,
            season=home_team.seasons.all().last(),
        )
```

The models involved are displayed below:

```
class League(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Season(models.Model):
    first_year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    second_year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    league = models.ForeignKey(
        League, related_name="seasons", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    seasons = models.ManyToManyField(Season, related_name="teams")


class Match(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(
        League, related_name="matches", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    season = models.ForeignKey(
        Season, related_name="matches", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team, related_name="home_matches", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team, related_name="away_matches", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

I understand the first error (`Item "None" of "Optional[Season]" has no attribute "league"`)

As `Seasons` refers to a `ManyToMany` field which can of course be None. 
I do not see what I'm doing wrong for the second error.

My main problem is that I'm not sure what the canonical way is to solve these errors. The ManyToMany field could always return an optional, but not using them is obviously the wrong answer. I could append a few `# type: ignore` statements to my code, but then I'm just circumventing the problem rather than solving it.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and - if so - what the correct way of using mypy in these circumstances is?

Comment: any update on this, i am facing the same problem indeed